# Who wins this game of high low Hurricane with wilds?

Tags: rules, wild-card

In a game of high low Hurricane with deuces and 2 jokers wild, who wins between one player with Ace joker and the other deuce deuce?

Here are the rules we were going by:

- Players must declare whether they are going for high, low, or both
- When going for both, the player must win both to win any
- Aces are high in the high, low in the low
- The lowest possible hand is Ace deuce
- In the high, at least, when two ranks are identical, the one using more naturals wins

For the high, Ace joker (pair of aces) wins because the ranks are the same, but the ace joker uses a natural ace.

The ranks for the low are the same (Ace deuce).
One hand used a natural ace, the other had a natural deuce (although deuces are wild).

As far as I can tell, it comes down to if a natural is better or stronger.  If it's stronger then deuce deuce wins the low because the opponent's natural ace is stronger.  If the natural is better then the natural two wins the low.

Comment: You are just going to need to decide on the rules for your home game.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would rule this a split pot. I haven't read anything that explicitly defines rules for dealing with wild cards, but in my mind the hand someone holds is the hand they hold. Changing that based on whether or not the hand contains a wild card seems akin to saying that a spade flush is worth more than a club flush (which is never the case in any poker game I've played).

Comment: I agree with @Jeffrey. There is no rule I've ever heard that "natural beats wild" when playing with wildcards. In this case both players effectively have A2, and split for low.

Comment: I have seen this rule, but I can't find the book the mentions it.  Maybe we should drop it, though.  Still, if anyone does use the rule, I'd like to see some good reasoning for which hand wins.